# Installing Boost libraries on Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, macos, boost-filesystem

I have followed the directions on the boost website. I have put the boost dir in the path.  I still cannot compile a C++ program using the boost libraries.  I am specifically trying to use the filesystem library.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

--TJB

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: When I compile a simple program as follows:

g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_40_0 example.cpp -o example

It seems to work just fine.  However, if I try to compile a program that uses the filesystem library within boost I get a long (too long to post here) list of compiler errors indicating that I cannot link to the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you compile the filesystem library? Many Boost libraries are header-only, but filesystem is one of the few that have to be compiled (and linked).

Instructions on how to do that can be found at points 5 and 6 of the [Getting Started on Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) page. Instructions specific to the filesystem lib are at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#Building

Comment: Ah. No I didn't.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured it out, at the end it wasn't that difficult:
http://www.thepinguin.net/2010/10/boost-on-snow-leopard-x86_64/